# Add Image To Crystal Report At Runtime

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I would like to add an image to a crystal report at runtime.

I am currently doing this using a second data table containing only a byte field and then a blob field on the report.  However this feels like a hack and if there is no data in the first primary table then for some reason the image does not show.

Is it possible to add an image with code or another method?

I'm using crystal reports for visual studio 2010.  Winforms project.  Either C# or VB.

Comment: Is it a static image? Why are you adding it at runtime instead of design time?

Comment: Ni noa, it is a company logo.  It is dynamic as it will change dependant on which company is using the software.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to store the logo on disk instead of in the database:

1. In Designer, insert a placeholder image.
2. Right-click the placeholder image, and click **Format Graphic**. On the **Picture** tab, next to **Graphic Location**, click the formula button. Enter the path there, or provide a formula which provides it.

At runtime, Crystal will substitute the image from the file.

If you want, you can use a parameter field in your formula. That way you can provide the path programmatically at runtime.

Comment: I'll need this one day. If using CR2008: Right-click image -> "Format Graphic" -> "Picture" tab -> "Graphic Location:" -> Enter file path as string

Comment: Thanks! I added that detail to the post.

Comment: I tired this via two methods: using a parameter as the full location of the file and as just the filename of the location (directory). Both unfortunately prompt me for the parameter when the report loads even though I'm clearly setting the parameter's value. Any idea?