# How to show a System.Drawing.Image in a Crystal Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, system.drawing.imaging

I have a crystal report in which an image 'CompanyLogo' have to be displayed on top of the report. The image I want to use is returned by a function call as a System.Drawing.Image.

`Image img = SomeClass.CompanyLogo()` //Function call returns the image needed.

Is there any way to display this image 'img' in crystal report without using any image path? If there how can I implement the same .? // C# code needed

Comment: Did you see [this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706662/add-image-to-crystal-report-at-runtime)

Comment: How about these: 
[post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23227513/insert-image-to-crystal-reports/23243126#23243126)
[post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27180838/displaying-image-in-crystal-reports-10-using-c-sharp-through-a-file-path-stored/27192414#27192414), or
[post 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27162526/how-to-view-dynamic-images-in-crystal-report-9-during-runtime-without-using-data/27192825#27192825)